# clases herencia y arrays c#

Tags: c#

Desde hace días que estoy estancado con un problema con un codigo de clases, herencias y la impresión de mi código. Les paso el código y la captura de mi error. No sé cómo arreglar ese problema.

Lo que está comentado es para la impresión manual de los números pero los imprime de forma vertical. Lo que tengo que hacer es imprimirlo de forma horizontal y estaba haciendo eso.

Lo que tengo que hacer es un display7leds. El usuario introduce un número por teclado, o aleatoriamente, y lo tiene que imprimir con barras y espacios cada número. Un ejemplo:

Así del 0 al 9 con el tamaño que se colocó en la variable "n"
adjunto el codigo
...

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace clases_y_herencia
    {
        class Program
        {
    
            public class dibujos
            {
                public string Vac { get;set; }
                public string Ar { get; set; }
                public string Ar2 { get; set; }
                public string Ar3 { get; set; }
                public string Ab { get; set; }
                public string Lad2 { get; set; }
                public string Lad1 { get; set; }
                 dibujos[] x = new dibujos[0];
                public dibujos()
                {
                    /*
                    Ar = " | ";
                    Ar2 = "| |";
    
                    Ar3 = "|_|";
    
                    Ab = " _ ";
    
                    Vac = "  ";
    
                    Lad2 = "_|";
    
                    Lad1 = "|_";
                   */
                   
    
                   x[0].Vac = " _";
                    x[1].Vac = "| |";
                    x[2].Vac = "|_|";
                    x[0].Ar = "  |";
                    x[1].Ar = "  |";
                    x[2].Ar = "  |";
                }
                public dibujos(string arriba, string abajo, string arriba2,
                   string arriba3, string vacio, string lado2, string lado1 )
                {
                    this.Ar = arriba;
                    this.Ar2 = arriba2;
                    this.Ar3 = arriba3;
                    this.Ab = abajo;
                    this.Vac = vacio;
                    this.Lad1 = lado2;
                    this.Lad2 = lado1;
    
                }
            }     
                class dibujos2 : dibujos
            {
                public int n = 10;  //ingresar cuantos numeros quiere uno   
                Random rnd = new Random();
                datos[] Numero = new datos[0];
                public void ingresar()
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref Numero, Numero.Length + n);
                    for (int i = 0; i < Numero.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Numero[i].digito = rnd.Next(1, 1);
                    }
                }
                public void Mostrar()
                {
                    //dibujos x = new dibujos();
                    dibujos[] x = new dibujos[0];
                    Array.Resize(ref Numero, Numero.Length + n);
                    for (int i = 0; i < Numero.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (Numero[i].digito == 1)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 2; i++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(x[i].Ar + " ");
                            }
    
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                       
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
    
                }
            }
    
            public struct datos
            {
                public int digito { get; set; }
                public datos(int numero)
                {
                    digito = numero;
                }
            }
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
    
                dibujos h = new dibujos();
                dibujos2 p = new dibujos2();
                p.ingresar();
    
                p.Mostrar();
                Console.ReadKey();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

...

[image: el unico problema es ese]

[image: tiene que quedar como esto tal cual]

Gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: Hola, puedes poner un ejemplo de que es lo que deseas hacer

Comment: @Japv                                                                       
 https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.diarioelectronicohoy.com%2Fblog%2Fdisplay-multiple-de-7-segmentos&psig=AOvVaw1ModgTa3uUGYPhuZLq9CLo&ust=1613423176944000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPi68Oyj6u4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI                                                                                      tengo que imprimirlo como ese display leds 7

Comment: @Japv subi una nueva imagen para que me entiendas mejor

Comment: Si ya te entiendo, pero en la imagen que pones, por ej el número 8 lo estás construyendo con más de "7 leds"

Comment: @Japv  si lose quiero hacerlo para x numeros el problema es al imprimir el array me aparece ese error nose porque

Comment: @Japv si quito todo lo que esta el array me imprime X numeros pero verticalmente y lo que quiero lograr es que vayan horizontalmente

Comment: datos[] Numero = new datos[0]; pones esto, no deberias poner datos[] Numero = new datos[n];? y pones tambien dibujos[] x = new dibujos[0]; estas haciendo un arreglo de un solo elemento, eso esta bien?

Comment: @Japv si no tengo ningun problema solo me aparece el error de la foto  lo del dibujos[] x = new dibujos[0] solo lo estoy inicializando en 0 luego lo acomodo en base a los digitos de n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var L1 = " __";             
var L2 = "|  |";
var L3 = "|__|";
var L4 = "  |";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if (i == 0)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(L1);
      Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
      Console.WriteLine(L2);
      Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
      Console.WriteLine(L3);
   }
   else if (i == 1)
   {
      Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 1);
      Console.WriteLine(L4);
      Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 2);
      Console.WriteLine(L4);
   }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo, el código funciona, solo debes adaptarlo a tu problema. La clave aquí es el **método SetCursorPosition** de la **clase Console**, este método lo que hace es ubicar el cursor en las coordenadas que deseamos y en esas coordenadas es donde se escribirá el caracter que queremos. En este ejemplo solo escribo el número **0** y el número **1**. Puedes mejorarlo tanto como desees.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se ve.

Comment: muchas gracias lo añadiré y te aviso como me va